# How do you add multiple divs, each with individual css properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting a random value from an array:

```
const randomDivArray = [1, 2, 3];
const randomDivGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomDivArray.length);
const randomNumberOfDivs = randomDivArray[randomDivGenerator];
```

How do I get a certain amount of divs to appear on the page depending on what the value of randomNumberOfDivs is? I need them to appear on the page spaced out equally.

Comment: hide all div and then show randomNumberOfDivs divs?

Comment: Yes, thanks I'll try that